# Reverse engineering a DLL

Tags: c#, dll, reverse-engineering

I'm in the process of creating a profile editor for a game. Main issue is to deal with figuring out the structure of a binary file that is used to store all the data.

To do so, I decompiled the source code and I'm going through the code that deals with saving (and reading) to/from the save-file. However, I ran into a wall. I have code similar to this:

```
if (this.entity == Q.FG(45768))
{
//read data in one manner
}

else if (this.entity == Q.FG(96583))
{
//read data in another manner
}
```

This appears in more places and can have quite a few `if then else` statements.

Now, I know the value of `this.entity` since it's value has been read from the save-file earlier in the code. However, I don't know the value of `Q.FG(int num)`. The code is written in C#.

`Q` is an internal static class and `FG(int num)` is an internal static method that returns a `string` type object. In order to continue, I need to know the output of that method for at least a few numbers.

Another problem is that the method is using dlls resource files and names and providing those manually has given me invalid results. I can check the output since the output for one of the numbers must match `this.entity`.

Is there a way I can call this method from somewhere and see the result that it returns?

I'm open to any way of doing so, be it with programming and invoking the method, or using a tool and trying to catch the value during the games execution.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Download [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) and reflect `FG`.

Comment: Or you can open the application with the debugger in Visual Studio and step through the `MSIL` code. In VS go to Debug/Attach To Process

Comment: Care to give a little bit more details?

How do I reflect, because all that typeof() and getType() stuff didn't really work out? How can I open a whole application with debugger?

Comment: Attach to process doesn't get any variables, if that was what you were refering at.

Comment: `FG` is a method of `Q`, if Q is a class it is a static method, if it is a property or field it is a instance method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodInfo info2 = Type.GetType("A.PW, Assembly-CSharp").GetMethod("G", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new Type[] { typeof(int) }, null);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((string) info2.Invoke(null, new object[] {75432}));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((string)info2.Invoke(null, new object[] {45634}));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((string)info2.Invoke(null, new object[] {70345}));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((string)info2.Invoke(null, new object[] {3456}));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((string)info2.Invoke(null, new object[] {4734}));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
    } 
}
```

This does it if the assembly is referenced in the solution. Had trouble with getting the names exactly right.